# Vue js sent multiple select box values (array) to text area and append the value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

[image]

I have a scenario and I will really appreciate any help. As shown in the image,
I have only multiple select box on the left where there are numbers and on the right this is text box, what I want to do is, when ever user clicks on the house numbers, it should come to the right text-area box, and will be able to append the values, from the text area as well.

Answer (score 1):

Get the selected value with the apropriate handler (`@input`, `@change`, etc.) and then `push` it in some array inside your `data()`;

Finally, bind this variable with the right-hand text-area.

Obs: once you didn't show the code, I tried help you using high level steps.

Comment: Thank you, it was easy with @change.